# Загрузка аудио-потока в буфер OpenAL, библиотеки ALUT и libaudio

Tags: документация, аудио, библиотеки

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите пожалуйста, натолкнулся на статью OpenAL, где утверждалось, что библиотека ALUT - устаревший API. И предлагался альтернативный вариант в виде libaudio (о такой библиотеке я впервые слышу, ничего найти не могу, находил что-то связаное с Debian, интересуюсь взаимодействием с Windows). Скажите, кто-нибудь пользовался ею (библиотекой)? Расскажите, как с ней взаимодействовать на Windows. Я планирую написать большой код, мне нужно почитать документацию об этой библиотеке, но я ничего не могу найти. 
Спасибо за внимание, извините за излишнюю лень, хочется услышать дельный совет от людей, которые этим уже занимались. Возможно, ALUT еще не так отмерла, но опять же, она указана как устаревший API.

Comment: Насколько мне известно это linux-библиотека (как линуксоид заявляю).

Comment: @beraliv как я понял, гнездо у них: http://radscan.com/nas.html Но про винды там скупо: Microsoft Windows using Cygwin.

@Gedweb а линкуксоид -- это серьёзно? Может медицина ещё может чем-то помочь?

Comment: @alexlz А вы, я так понимаю, пользователь зонта или Win$.

Вы та авторитетно заявляете об этом. Может быть вы еще когда-нибудь пользовались GNU/Linux.

Comment: @deterok Да, было. Но говорили, что разработчик дистрибутива (slackware) в те времена пил слишком много пива...

И ещё, что в данном контексте означает "зонт"?

Comment: Ну это зонд, только зонт :)

Я прошу не обижаться на мои слова, просто GNU/Linux мой хлеб (работа связана с этой осью). Я тоже раньше отказывался от его использования, писал в основном под Win, но в итоге, после глубокого изучения и нахождения понимания его идей(не всех правда) полностью перешел на его использование.